# Hacer scroll web multiframe en navegador web Luakit

Tags: lua, navegador-web, vim

Uso [**Luakit**](https://luakit.github.io/luakit/) de manera habitual desde hace algunas semanas. La verdad es que para los que estamos acostumbrados a usar [vim](http://www.vim.org/) como editor de textos es una pequeña maravilla. Si encima usas [awesome](https://awesomewm.org/) y te gusta [Lua](http://www.lua.org), es la combinación perfecta.

No obstante algunas páginas no tienen en cuenta este tipo de navegadores y la dependencia de multitud de llamadas absurdas a javascript para navegar por el documento nos obligan a usar el ratón.

Al tema, soy bastante torpe así que no he encontrado la manera de **seleccionar en que frame quiero hacer o scroll** desde el teclado cuando navego y me veo obligado a tener que usar el ratón.

Por ejemplo en una página con dos frames, si quiero mover el scroll de alguna de ella no tengo manera (típica página de documentación de javadoc o [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), con las clases en el frame izquierdo y la explicación de la que pinches en el izquierdo).